# Can you increase capacitance of capacitor by sandwiching a high dielectric constant material between two strong insulators?

Tags: electrostatics, capacitance, dielectric

My very limited research into dielectric materials has suggested that the higher the dielectric constant of a material, the less insulating it is. So why not just have some material with extremely high permittivity sandwiched in between two extremely strong insulators. Shouldn't that result in a greater increase in the value of absolute permittivity relative to the increase in distance (in regards to a parallel plate capacitor), hence resulting in a greater overall capacitance as given by the equation:

C = ε(A/d)

Also is it true that conductive materials are considered to have an infinite dielectric constant? If so, why is it not used in the way I suggested above?

I believe there is a flaw in my understanding of what's happening and would appreciate some clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding more layers to the dielectric stack, high dielectric constant or not, will not increase the capacitance. Recall the formula for the equivalent capacitance of series-connected capacitors:
$$C_{eq}^{-1} = C_1^{-1} + C_2^{-1} + ...$$
which, for capacitors of equal area, can also be written as
$$c_{eq}^{-1} = t_1/\epsilon_1 + t_2/\epsilon_2 + ...$$
where $c_{eq}$ denotes the equivalent capacitance per unit area and $t_i$ denotes the thickness of dielectric $i$.

It is true that, in some sense (at least at steady state), conductors can be viewed as being infinitely polarizable. If there is a conductive layer in the capacitor, it will simply have no effect on the equivalent capacitance.